# Executing test from appium generating an ElementnotSelectableException

Tags: maven, selenium, appium, appium-ios

While running my test case in appium using maven and testng, i am facing this error, not understanding why is this happening.
I am working on Intellij and below are the error and pom.xml file

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51681', transport: 'socket'

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotSelectableException

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes.<clinit>(ErrorCodes.java:107)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<clinit>(AppiumDriver.java:46)
    at mobileautomation.TestApp.setUp(TestApp.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotSelectableException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 26 more


===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Pom.xml file:
This is the pom file having dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.unation.mobileautomation</groupId>
    <artifactId>UnationMobileAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-beta4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3-alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>4.4-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-beta4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20080701</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To write basic websockets against -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To run websockets in embedded server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To run websockets client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.klieber</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
                <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
                <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.0.M0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-beta3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
                <version>2.23</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.8</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
                <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Has your file done an import for ElementNotSelectableException?  what does your pom.xml file look like?

Comment: I've added the pom.xml file you can see it and can you brief more about ElementNotSelectableException.

Comment: looking in your stack trace, am I correct that "at mobileautomation.TestApp.setUp(TestApp.java:30)" is in your code?  if so, does TestApp import ElementNotSelectableException?

Comment: Yeah you're correct, i am having a problem in importing ElementNotSelectableException, can you please guide me in it.

Comment: Probably not.  8-(  You should check your project configuration in intelliJ.  Do you have the same problem if you just run "mvn clean install" ?

Comment: it's also giving error while running from maven

Comment: might want to clean out your local copy of maven repo to start fresh?  Perhaps the copy of selenium is messed up.

Comment: @RamizHasan You have repeated instances of seleniumhq, once with 3...4 beta and then again 3...3 beta... also 3....2 beta Once without any version. You need to clean up the pom.xml. On a side note the appium version is pretty old - any reason you are using it.

Comment: @Grasshopper i find this version here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/2.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly likely caused by incompatibility of Selenium server with Phantom JS, because you're using beta version.

So try upgrading it to the next stable, for example by the following lines in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
  <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then run `mvn dependency:tree` to build and display the dependency tree for this project.

See: [`org.seleniumhq.selenium` at MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium).